# Optimizing the way I get data for the drop down lists

Tags: java, drop-down-menu

I have a web application that I deploy on a Tomcat web server.
This web app has many forms that contain drop down lists.
I want to optimize the way I load these lists.

For instance, what I'm doing :
- I have a singleton class with final static ArrayList fields.
- So, when I call the singleton the first time, it loads all the lists
- I call those lists with a getter for each list

Is it possible to tell Tomcat to load those lists when the web app is deployed ? If It can do it, how can I access to these lists ?

Thank you

Comment: Where is it loading the lists from?  A static file?  A more general approach here might be a 'warm-up' script that hits a bunch of paths on your server as the final stage of the deployment process.  Then you could "get" all of the lists and load them right after deployment, during warm-up.

Comment: The list is loaded from a web service.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) that stores the lists in the Application scope in its `contextInitialized` method.

Comment: I believe you mean in the `contextInitialized` method, but +1

Comment: Thank you for your proposition. Please, can we have some code showing us how to load those lists with the ServletContextListener and how to make them accessible for the whole application ?